# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined using React

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, api

I'm new in React and I'm doing a little app with PokeAPI. I have a component called PokemonDetail in which I want to show the details of a pokemon, but the app throws me the next error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'front_default' of undefined

my component looks like this:

```
import React from "react";

const PokemonDetail = ({ pokemon }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="text-center">{pokemon.name}</div>
      <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt={pokemon.name} />
      {pokemon.id}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PokemonDetail;
```

And the App component from which the PokemonDetail recive the prop of pokemon looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import PokeAPI from "../apis/PokeAPI";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import PokemonDetail from "./PokemonDetail";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { pokemon: '' };

  onTermSubmit = async term => {
    try {
      const response = await PokeAPI.get(`pokemon/${term}`);
      this.setState({ pokemon: response.data });
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("No existe");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row mt-3">
          <div className="col">
            <SearchBar onFormSubmit={this.onTermSubmit} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row mt-3">
          <div className="col-9" />
          <div className="col-3">
            <PokemonDetail pokemon={this.state.pokemon} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I don't understand why it throws me this error because only throws it with this and other properties of the json. With the `name` property works and wait until I send it some props, same with the `id` but no with the `front_default` property, which is a url of a image.

Comment: Do not assign an empty string to the 'pokemon' variable if you know that will store an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ajax is slower than react rendering, you can use a loading component before you get the data.

```html
const PokemonDetail = ({ pokemon }) => {
  if(pokemon.sprites == undefined){
      return(
        <div>
            Loading...
        </div>
      );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="text-center">{pokemon.name}</div>
      <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt={pokemon.name} />
      {pokemon.id}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Very likely just an AJAX issue, your component renders before it has time to complete your request to the API. Try adding an additional check before rendering the image.

```
import React from "react";

const PokemonDetail = ({ pokemon }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="text-center">{pokemon.name}</div>
       {pokemon.sprites ? (
        <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt={pokemon.name} />
        ) : ( 
          null
        )
       }
      {pokemon.id}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PokemonDetail;
```

Comment: But why work with some properties of the json and with others throw error?

Comment: You know, I wish I had a better way of explaining this, but sometimes when you communicate with an API it just takes some properties to load longer than others :/

Answer (score 1):

@ZHAOXIANLONG gave you the best solution (use a loading component until you receive data), but, if you do not use a loading component, you can use the **get** method from **lodash** library [1] in order to avoid a possible error.

```
import React from "react";
import _ from 'lodash';

const PokemonDetail = ({ pokemon }) => {
    const front_default = _.get(pokemon, 'sprites.front_default', 'DEFAULT_VALUE');
    const name = _.get(pokemon, 'name', 'DEFAULT_VALUE');

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="text-center">{pokemon.name}</div>
            <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt={pokemon.name} />
            {pokemon.id}
        </div>
    );
};

export default PokemonDetail;
```

where the third parameter ('DEFAULT_VALUE') is a default value that will be used if the lodash can not retrieve a value for your query.

PS: I advise you to use lodash even in @ZHAOXIANLONG solution if you know that your API Server can be changed.

[1] https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get

Answer (score 0):

The initial state is `{ pokemon: '' }`; `pokemon` is an empty string. `PokemonDetail` is referring to `pokemon.sprites.front_default`, but `pokemon` is initially a string and a string does not have a field called `sprites`.

If you are expecting pokemon to eventually become an object, you could initialize it to something that looks like an object:

```
state = { pokemon: { sprites: {front_default: '' }}};
```